# Disabling Bash Commands in, Other Interactive Programs

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, shell, kali-linux

I was using Kali Linux, And I don't want bash Commands to be run it other Interactive programs, Like if you run `msfconsole` in Meterpreter you can still do `ls`, In Metasploit that's not a problem, but I am trying to learn PowerShell. When I do `pwsh` I can still use bash commands -- that's kinda odd. Help me with disabling the bash commands in PowerShell.

Copy and Paste of what I have done:

```
root@kali:~# pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.
PS /root/Documents/tmp> ls
chall  john  peda-session-chall.txt
```

In Powershell, It should not run `ls` command. But as I am using it in bash, I am able to run that command, And I want to Stop it

Contents of `$PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I have tried looking for some flags like `--no-bash` but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can disable OS commands in PowerShell.

By definition, PowerShell is first trying its own commands or aliases, and if not found, it is searching in underlying OS for executable. 
But, I would say that is the same for other shells also. Even bash. In your example, command `ls` is not builtin command in bash, but located within your `$PATH`. On the other hand, `times` is built in command.

```sh
igor@pc:~$ which times
igor@pc:~$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

Notice that above I refer to the underlying OS and not the previous shell. PowerShell will **not** execute built-in commands from bash. If you try `eval`, `unset`, `times` or [others](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html), you will get the error `CommandNotFoundException`

```
PS /home/igor> times
times : The term 'times' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ times
+ ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (times:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS /home/igor> exit
igor@pc:~$ times
0m0.078s 0m0.141s
0m36.063s 0m29.406s
```

Comment: Thank You Very much... I will try to Poke around Path for it.